# read line by line and do a if command

Tags: bash, if-statement, count, while-loop

I have the following problem. I have a file like this:

```
134 Apple
345 Strawberries
45 Pears
1450 Oranges
```

what I would like to do is reading each line and IF the value is above, for examples 70, write the string to another file like:

```
134 Apple
345 Strawberries
1450 Oranges
```

I think that the key are the commands **while read line** and **if** but I do not know how to combine them

I've tried (just to have a visual print of the results, because I do not know how to have the prompt directed to a file in a "if command")

```
READ=awk '{print $1}' mylist.txt
if [ $READ -gt 70]; then echo "you have more that 70 fruits"
fi
```

but it doesn't work because (I think) it reads not only "numbers" but also "words" or reads all the numbers and not just an unique number. It gaves me this error: "unary operator expected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read count fruit ; do
  if [ $count -gt 70 ]; then
    echo $count $fruit
  fi
done < mylist.txt > newlist.txt
```

Writes output to newlist.txt.

The reason you get "unary operator expected" is because all the numbers are put after each other in your READ variable and thus your if statement becomes:

```
if [ 134 345 45 1450 -gt 70]; then
```

which bash does not know how to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

how about do it with this one-liner:

```
awk '($1+0)>70{print > "new.txt"}' file
```